# How to use for loop in reactjs to send data to get request in flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I have implemented multiple web-cam Streaming in flask rendering index.html. I want to do same using react framework but can't figure out how to do it. I tried using for loop as shown below in App.js but it dosent seem to work and i can't figure the correct method for it.

This is index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Multiple Live Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Multiple Live Streaming</h3>
            {%for i in range(0,2)%}
                <img src="{{ url_for('stream', id=i) }}" width="50%">
            {%endfor%}
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is app.py in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, Response
import cv2
import threading
app = Flask(__name__)

lock = threading.Lock()

@app.route('/stream/<string:id>',methods = ['GET'])
def stream(id):
      return Response(generate(id), mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
   

def find_camera(id):
    cameras = [0, 1]
    return cameras[int(id)]

def generate(camera_id):

   global lock
   cam = find_camera(camera_id)
   vc = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
   
   if vc.isOpened():
      rval, frame = vc.read()
   else:
      rval = False

   
   while rval:
      # wait until the lock is acquired
      with lock:
        
         rval, frame = vc.read()
         
         if frame is None:
            continue

         (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)

         # ensure the frame was successfully encoded
         if not flag:
            continue

      
      yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
   
   vc.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   host = "127.0.0.1"
   port = 8000
   debug = False
   options = None
   app.run(host, port, debug, options)
```

This is app.js where i want to implement same as implemented in index.html:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {%for i in range(0,2)%}
          <img src={'/stream/{i}'} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why dont you just render two  <img src={'/stream/{id}'} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> one after another ? or is this a variable how many numbers of <img> will be there ?

Comment: " tried using for loop as shown below in App.js but it doesn't seem to work ", you might get some errors? what are they? debug and fix your code. What you have written as React code is not JSX.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Yes its how many numbers of img will be there. As i have to multiple stream, i.e 2 live stream at same time thats why the for loop

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Its syntax error for for loop. How should i define it?

Comment: so your decision of the number of image tags depend on what ? i mean which variable in your component ? because i see none

Comment: It's actually {i} not {id} , pasted wrong code

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const imageArray = []
  for( let i= 0;i < numberOfSream ;i ++ ) imageArray.push( <img src={'/stream/{id}'} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> )

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        
          {  imageArray }

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This dosen't show the live stream. Shows "logo" on the react app.

Comment: it wont because you have to pass the properties into img tag correctly

Comment: Okay i figured out the problem in index.py. But now it shows the error for "/stream/{i}"  in img src as invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{i}'. And when just pass "/stream/1" or "/stream/0" it works perfectly

Comment: try `/stream/${i}`  watch the backtick